# Nested reactive forms - ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I can't figure it out what am I doing wrong here. I keep getting: ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'Properties -> 2 -> SelectOptions -> Url'.

I've searched through similair questions, but I coudln't find what's wrong

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="configForm" style="overflow: auto;">
                <div class="center">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="input-field">
                        <mat-label>Display name</mat-label>
                        <input formControlName="DisplayName" matInput>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <h3 style="margin: 0;">Properties:</h3>
                    <div formArrayName="Properties" *ngFor="let item of properties.controls; let i = index;" class="outline-inputs">

                        <div [formGroupName]="i">
                            <mat-form-field class="input-field">
                                <mat-label>ID</mat-label>
                                <input formControlName="Id" matInput>
                            </mat-form-field>

                            <ng-container *ngIf="item.get('SelectOptions')?.value">
                                <div formGroupName="SelectOptions">
                                    <h3 style="margin: 0;">Select options:</h3>
                                    <mat-form-field class="input-field">
                                        <mat-label>Url</mat-label>
                                        <input formControlName="Url" matInput>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </form>
```

This is how I create form .ts:

```
get properties() { return this.configForm.controls.Properties as FormArray; }
configData(data: ConfigurationType){

this.configForm.get("DisplayName").setValue(data.DisplayName);

for (const item of data.Properties) {
  if( item.SelectOptions ){
    this.properties.push(this.formBuilder.group({
      Id: [item.Id, Validators.required]
      SelectOptions: [this.formBuilder.group({
        Url: [item.SelectOptions.Url, Validators.required]
      })]
    }))
  } else {
    this.properties.push(this.formBuilder.group({
      Id: [item.Id, Validators.required]
    })) 
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In general a JSON array should to have the same structure each element. And a FormArray too. Yo're try to create a FormArray with different structure each element. I suggest you create always the formGroup, with a value of Url, e.g. the string "null" (or "no-url"), and check this value

```
for (const item of data.Properties) {
    this.properties.push(this.formBuilder.group({
      Id: [item.Id, Validators.required]
      SelectOptions: [this.formBuilder.group({
        Url: [item?.SelectOptions?item.SelectOptions.Url:'no-url',
                Validators.required]
      })]
    }))
}
```

BTW, I like use the method "get" instead of use controls:

```
get properties() { 
  return this.configForm.get('Properties') as FormArray; 
}
```

And the tags "formArrayName and formGroup" in the way

```
<!--in a div the formArrayName-->
<div formArrayName="Properties">
 <!--if the *ngFor the [formGroupName]="i"-->
  <div *ngFor="let item of properties.controls; let i = index;" 
     [formGroupName]="i" class="outline-inputs">
      ...
      <ng-container *ngIf="item.get('SelectOptions').value!='no-url'">
      </ng-container>
  <div >
</div>
```